# much clothes or many clothes

Tags: grammar

Clothes is an uncountable noun and is plural in nature.

According to grammar books, "much" is used for uncountable nouns and "many" is used for countable nouns.

Surprisingly, I see other people raising same questions in other forums before and quite a number of people suggested "many clothes" should be used.

I know some people may suggest using "a lot of clothes" to avoid ambiguity; but still I want to get the grammatic concept right between "much" and "many" on uncountable nouns.

Is "many clothes" really correct?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

*Clothes*, like *oats*, is both plural **and** uncountable.

- *a bowl of *bean/beans*, *a bowl of *oat/oats*, *a bowl of rice/*rices*

Since they're plural, *clothes* and *oats* take plural verbs, even if they are uncountable.

- *The oats/beans **were** delicious.*
- *The rice/milk was delicious*.
- *The clothes **are** on the floor.*
- *The hat is on the floor.*

As for *much/many*, it's more complex.  *Many of the clothes* means considering each piece separately, and it's plural and essentially countable.

- *Many of their clothes need repair.*

If you want to use *much*, don't use *clothes* -- use *clothing* instead, because that's definitely mass and singular and works where *clothes* wouldn't:

- *Much of their clothing was swept away by the storm.*
- *?*Much of their clothes was swept away by the storm.*

Comment: thank you John ^^

Comment: the question was "_Is "many clothes" really correct_?" In your post there's no answer to it.

Comment: A bare 'many clothes' sounds unnatural to my ears, John. But I'm used to 'a lot of clothes', and 'You have too many clothes'!